# How to use apply() in pandas with other columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas

As an exercise in Pandas, I am trying to analyse the best strategies for wordle. I found a list of 5 letter words and I am trying to create a dataFrame with the words and the number of each letter these words have.

I have manage to do this using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

words_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/charlesreid1/five-letter-words/master/sgb-words.txt', sep="\n", header=None)

words_df.rename(columns={0:'words'}, inplace=True)

alphabet_string = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)


for letter in alphabet_list:
  words_df[letter] = 0

letter_count_list = []
for row_index, word in enumerate(words_df['words']):

    letter_count_list.append([])

    for column_index, letter in enumerate(alphabet_list):

        letter_count = word.count(letter)
        letter_count_list[row_index].append(letter_count)

words_df.iloc[:,1:] = letter_count_list
words_df
```

I get exactly what I want, which is the following dataframe:

```
    words   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
0   which   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   there   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   their   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   about   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   would   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
5752    osier   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5753    roble   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5754    rumba   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
5755    biffy   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
5756    pupal   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

The code works perfectly, however, my main goal here is to learn Pandas and I know that using a for loop is not the best way to achieve this result. I have tried using the .apply() method, but I could not get it to work. What is the "pandas way" of achieving the same result?

Extra: I know that my Python skills are not the best, I would also appreciate comments on my code.

Comment: See my newer answer, which works _right_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) function, which returns a dict containing unique elements of a string/list and their counts, then convert it to a dataframe, fill NaNs, and assign it back to the original dataframe:

```
from collections import Counter

letter_cols = df.columns[1:]
df[letter_cols] = pd.DataFrame(df['words'].apply(Counter).tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int)[letter_cols]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      words  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
0     which  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
1     there  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     their  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     about  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
4     would  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
...     ... .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
5752  osier  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5753  roble  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5754  rumba  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5755  biffy  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
5756  pupal  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0

[5757 rows x 27 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** this doesn't work perfectly, as the counts don't increment as there are more of the same letter in a word, e.g. for row 5755, `f` should be 2 because there are two `f`'s in `biffy`, but it's only 1.

Original answer:

---

There's actually a really concise way to do exactly this what you're trying to do: [`<column>.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). It takes a separator string, and splits all the strings in that column by the separator, and creates a *one-hot encoded* dataframe out of them (exactly what you're trying to do):

```
>>> df['words'].str.get_dummies('')
      a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
0     0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
1     0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
4     0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
...  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
5752  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5753  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5754  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5755  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
5756  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

To add that back to the original dataframe:

```
tmp_df = df['words'].str.get_dummies('')
df[tmp_df.columns] = tmp_df
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      words  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
0     which  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
1     there  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     their  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     about  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
4     would  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0
...     ... .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
5752  osier  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5753  roble  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5754  rumba  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5755  biffy  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
5756  pupal  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0

[5757 rows x 27 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

This how I will go about it and avaoid lambda because it is an anticlimax in pandas

1. Add temp column which is a list of each letter in words
2. Explode the df on column 1 above
3. Apply pd.get_dummies on column 2
4. 3 above gives frequency of each letter in 2
5. groupby outcome in 4 and sum, gives a tally of each letter per index
6. Leverage pd.join to pin 5 back to original df.
7. drop temp column from the df

Code below

```
words_df['words1']=(list(map(','.join, words_df['words'])))#disintegrate words into letters
s= (words_df.drop(columns='words1')#drop new added column
    .join(#Join original df to computed outcome
        pd.get_dummies(#pd.get_dummies method
            words_df.assign(words1=words_df['words1'].str.split(',')).explode('words1')['words1'],prefix='', prefix_sep='')#raw breakdown by letters
        .groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()#groupby index and sum letters per index
    )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are really good solutions. I tested how fast they are using your data. It seems `get_dummies`+`groupby` is faster than `collections.Counter`.

```
def richardec():
    letter_cols = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    words_df[letter_cols] = pd.DataFrame(words_df['words'].apply(Counter).tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int)[letter_cols]
    return words_df

def wwnde():
    words_df['words1']=(list(map(','.join, words_df['words'])))#disintegrate words into letters
    s= (words_df.drop(columns='words1')#drop new added column
        .join(#Join original df to computed outcome
            pd.get_dummies(#pd.get_dummies method
                words_df.assign(words1=words_df['words1'].str.split(',')).explode('words1')['words1'],prefix='', prefix_sep='')#raw breakdown by letters
            .groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()#groupby index and sum letters per index
        )
       )
    return s

def list_Series_get_dummies():
    # this is the same as @wwnde's answer
    # the only difference is that instead of separating the letters of 
    # each word with a comma and then later splitting on it, 
    # it just creates lists from the letters and explodes them
    # otherwise exactly same
    out = words_df.join(pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(map(list, words_df['words'])).explode()).groupby(level=0).sum())
    return out

%timeit -n 1000 richardec()
60.9 ms ± 4.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 wwnde()
56.7 ms ± 2.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 list_Series_get_dummies()
50.8 ms ± 5.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```